# tip calculator crased when call to calculate

Tags: java, android, calculator

My code is:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText amt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill_amt);
    final EditText tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill_per);
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

    Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.toString());
            double tip_per = Double.parseDouble(tip.toString());
            double tip_cal = (amount * tip_per) / 100;
            result.setText("Result : " + Double.toString(tip_cal));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

please correct the error shown in this coding 
android studio is also showing warning on Result.text
something about 'use resource string with placeholder'

[i'm following this webpage's tutorial](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-tip-calculator/)

Comment: we need to see your stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tying to parse `EditText` into `Double` Error -`amt.toString()` and `tip.toString()`. Which is incorrect(Not Possible at all).

Replace this:

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.toString());
double tip_per = Double.parseDouble(tip.toString());
```

With this:

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.getText().toString());
double tip_per = Double.parseDouble(tip.getText().toString());
```

Comment: thanks brother you saved me a headache ,,,one more thing is that when i try to calculate 10 % of 100000000 the result is 1.0e7..... why is that... is there any solution for long degints

Comment: Consider accepting answer and upvote to thanks me. Although restrict user to input large values > 100,000.